# Setting up a Mercurial Repository for Go Packages

Tags: mercurial, go

I am struggling to setup a local Mercurial repository for go packages.

All mercurial package directories can are under the following url:

```
https://server.example.com/go-packages/
```

I can clone a package via:

```
hg clone https://server.example.com/go-packages/packagename
```

That works fine.

When I want to install the package with the `go` command line:

```
go get server.example.com/go-packages/packagename
```

I get the following error:

```
package server.example.com/go-packages/packagename: unrecognized import path "server.example.com/go-packages/packagename"
```

But when I do it as explained in http://golang.org/cmd/go/ :

```
go get server.example.com/go-packages/packagename.hg
```

It works perfectly.

In the above document they talk about a `<meta>` flag. So I created a index.html with the following entry:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix hg repo-root">
        <title>packagename</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>packagename</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Update:

When I do a `wget -O- https://server.example.com/go-packages/packagename/?go-get=1  --no-check-certificate` I get:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix hg repo-root">
        <title>packagename</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>packagename</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Update 2

I saw, that my content was wrong (copy paste error) now I changed it to:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="go-import" content="server.example.com/go-packages/packagename hg https://server.example.com/go-packages/packagename" />
        <title>packagename</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>packagename</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where `go-packages` is a directory containing the mercurial repository `packagename`.

But still `go get server.example.com/go-packages/packagename` is not working.

Comment: I would try for the `content` attribute '`server.example.com hg https://server.example.com/go-packages/packagename`'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3099) (and attached [code review](http://codereview.appspot.com/5660051/)), and [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=0af5bcfdb4c1):

- make sure your "import-prefix hg repo-root" follows the right format

  - The import-alias-prefix must be a prefix or exact match of the
    package being fetched with "`go get`".
  - The full-repo-root must be a full URL root to a repository containing
    a scheme and *not* containing a "`.vcs`" qualifier.
  - The `vcs` is one of "`git`", "`hg`", "`svn`", etc.
- make sure the page fetch from `https://<import>?go-get=1`  is indeed you `index.html` page (not `index.htm` or any other `DirectoryIndex` directive, if this is setup in an `httpd.conf` file for instance)

> If the import-alias-prefix is not an exact match for the import,
>   another HTTP fetch is performed, at the declared root (which does
>   *not* need to be the domain's root).
>
> For example, assuming that "`camlistore.org/pkg/blobref`" declares
>   in its HTML head:
>
> ```
> <meta name="go-import" content="camlistore.org git https://camlistore.org/r/p/camlistore" />
> ```
>
> ... then:
>
> ```
> $ go get camlistore.org/pkg/blobref
> ```
>
> ... looks at the following URLs:
>
> ```
> https://camlistore.org/pkg/blobref?go-get=1
> http://camlistore.org/pkg/blobref?go-get=1
> https://camlistore.org/?go-get=1
> http://camlistore.org/?go-get=1
> ```
>
> Ultimately it finds, at the root (`camlistore.org/`), the same `go-import`:
>
> ```
> <meta name="go-import" content="camlistore.org git https://camlistore.org/r/p/camlistore" />
> ```
>
> ... and proceeds to trust it, checking out git `//camlistore.org/r/p/camlistore`
>   at the import path of "`camlistore.org`" on disk.

Comment: See my Updates. Did some changes with your input, but it is still not working.